# TYPO3 get all Images without References

Tags: typo3, typo3-9.x

It seems not possible to use the Filelist Module to get a list of all unused images (I mean all images without references). I checked the extensions, but it seems there is no Extension for this task. What are possible solutions to this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way would be a SQL query. In a very simple example it could look like this:

```
SELECT * FROM sys_file WHERE uid NOT IN (SELECT uid_local FROM sys_file_reference)
```

Each "used" file *should* have an entry in the `sys_file_reference` table. So, every file (`sys_file`-record) with *no* occurrence in `sys_file_reference` *should* be unused.

**Be careful!**
Besides references to single files, files can be in use via folders. The query above does not check these uses.